# Rooted device throwing FileSystemException

Tags: android, timber-android

I'm seeing a rooted Samsung device (Galaxy A70 with Android 8.1) on Crashlytics throwing following:

```
Caused by java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /data/user/0/.../cache/....0.log.lck: Invalid argument
   at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:177)
   at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
   at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
   at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:460)
   at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:403)
   at at.allaboutapps.android.filelogger.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:25)
   at at.allaboutapps.android.filelogger.FileLoggerTree.<init>(FileLoggerTree.kt:15)
   at com.hagleitner.hagi360.application.App.initLogging(App.kt:175)
   at com.hagleitner.hagi360.application.App.onCreate(App.kt:89)
```

Any idea to why this could be happening?